# fraction power of operators in $C_0$ semigroup.

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Let $X$ be Banach space, and $\{Z(t)\}_{t\geq 0}\subseteq B(X)$ be the $C_0$-Semigroup of operators defined on $X$. Moreover, let $A$ be the infinitesimal generator of $\{Z(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$. A fractional power of any closed linear operator $F$ is defined, when $(-\infty,0)\subset \rho(F)$(the resolvent set.) and the set $\{\lambda(\lambda-F)^{-1}:0<\lambda<\infty\}$ is bounded. It is noted that any such conditions do not imply that $F$ generates a semigroup.

My problem is, that I have to consider the fractional powers of operators in $\{Z(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$. i.e. $[Z(t)]^r$ , for $r\in R$ and $t>0$. Then when is it possible? 
If I consider, only those semigroups whose generator  satisfies above conditions and its fractional powers are defined. then as we know $Z(t)=e^{tA}$, then is it possible to take its fractional powers? because integer powers are very well defined through Banach algebra. Problem is just with its fraction powers.